# Shimming module in webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, shim

I'm building a typescript project with a module, `tiny-worker`, as a dependency of a dependency (not a direct dependency). `tiny-worker` uses node's `child_process` which doesn't exist in the browser.

I followed Webpack's shimming guide and added the following to my webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'tiny-worker': 'Worker'
    })
  ],
```

However, when I try to run webpack it still complains about `child_process` in `tiny-worker`

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/tiny-worker/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/tiny-worker/lib/index.js 8:11-35
 @ ./node_modules/pollenium-anemone/node/src/classes/MissiveGenerator.js
 @ ./node_modules/pollenium-anemone/node/main.js
 @ ./src/globals/anemoneClient.ts
 @ ./src/classes/BopManager.ts
 @ ./src/classes/Market.tsx
 @ ./src/globals/markets.ts
 @ ./src/app.tsx
 @ ./src/index.ts
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./src/index.ts
```

How can i get Webpack to use `window.Worker` instead of `import Worker from 'tiny-worker'`

Comment: Why would you need tinyworker at all? The whole point of tinyworker is to give Node functionality that browsers already natively support (namely, [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)) so rather than trying to come up with a shim _for_ a shim, try to remove the shim instead?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't want tiny-worker. tiny-worker is a dependency of a dependency. I can't just remove it without forking the 1st dependency, which I don't want to do.

Comment: So ask the people who make that dependency, first. SO is your last resort, not the first place to ask, and Node libraries are all open source, almost all of them on github, which means they have an issue tracker to ask this question on. The people there are _far more likely_ to know exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using `module-replace-webpack-plugin`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-replace-webpack-plugin

```
plugins: [
    new ModuleReplaceWebpackPlugin({
      modules: [{
        test: /^tiny-worker$/,
        replace: './shims/Worker.js'
      }]
    })
  ]
```

and created `shims/Worker.js` which simply re-exports window.Worker

`export default window.Worker`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the need here? Environment constraints or oddly novel use case?

Comment: @trebleCode I don't use webpack very often, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Isn't this a common use case? Dependency X doesn't work in the browser so you swap it with dependecy Y?